# Powershell find a word in a line that contains a phrase

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that goes through a text file and finds the name of a variable that I need and stores it as a variable. Say somewhere in thext I have the following line:

`Friend Const STR_NAME As String = "Test Name"`

Now I want to extract the word `STR_NAME`  in a line that contains `"Test Name"` and `Friend Const`. I know that the word I need `STR_NAME` is the third word in that line. So what I want is essentially something like this:

`$name = function("Test Name",Friend Const)`

which gives the third string in the line, which in this case is:

`$name = "STR_NAME"`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: [Select-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/parsing-text-with-powershell-1-3/) is what you need. Though the details of the implementation you need are unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Select-String -SimpleMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#-simplematch) to find the line containing `Test Name` then for the captured [`.Line`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.line?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#microsoft-powershell-commands-matchinfo-line) you can split by spaces and select the 2nd index of the array (3rd word):

```bash
Select-String path\to\textfile.txt -Pattern 'Test Name' -SimpleMatch |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Line.Split(' ')[2] }
```

Comment: Yes this works! Though I had to put an index [4], I guess it counts the white space spaces too. The problem is that it needs to include "Friend Const" on the same line, since there are many lines with "Test Name". Is it possible to use this somehow to find a word on a preceeding line? Say we have a line 1 `<data name="STR_NAME" xml:space="preserve">` and then a line below `<value>Test Name</value>`? So we know Test Name but want to get STR_NAME?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just parsing out the variable name, you could also get the variable object type and its value.

Something like

```
$var = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\test.txt' {
    'Friend Const\s+(\w+)\s+(?:as\s+)?(\w+)?\s*=\s*(.+)' { 
        [PsCustomObject]@{ Name = $Matches[1]; Type = $Matches[2]; Value = $Matches[3] }
    }
}

$var
```

Output:

```
Name     Type   Value      
----     ----   -----      
STR_NAME String "Test Name"
```

so you have

```
$var.Name   # --> STR_NAME
$var.Type   # --> String
$var.Value  # --> "Test Name"
```

There could be more lines like that in your file, so `$var` could be an array of objects with these properties

---

If you like to create a function for this, here's the idea:

```
function Find-Variable {
    param(
        [string]$Path,
        [string]$Declaration,
        [string]$Value
    )
    switch -Regex -File $Path {
        "$Declaration\s+(\w+)\s+(?:as\s+)?(\w+)?\s*=\s*($Value)" { 
            [PsCustomObject]@{ Name = $Matches[1]; Type = $Matches[2]; Value = $Matches[3] }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$var = Find-Variable -Path 'D:\Test\test.txt' -Declaration 'Friend Const' -Value '"Test Name"'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks like something that I am after! I tested the function as follows: `$var = Find-Variable -Path 'D:\Test\test.txt' -Declaration 'Friend Const' -Value '"Test Name"'` then just print this variable out `echo $var` and just to verify underneath it I printed `echo "test"` but nothing was printing.

Comment: @kmrydlx `echo` is alias to cmdlet `Write-Output`. In your test case it would be better to use `Write-Host`, but you can simply do just `$var` and `"test"` to output to the console window. Of course, you will have to set the path to your actual file. `D:\Test\test.txt` was only for me to have a test file, your path will probably point to some .vb file

Comment: Thanks, I just have a variable `$DirPath` that stores the path to the file. I put `$var` but nothing is printed out. As a matter of fact, no other string can be printed out after I call this function. But I can print out things before calling this function. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @kmrydlx show us some of the actual file. I have a feeling you are trying to get this out of an xml file which is not at all what you posted in the question..

Comment: Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong. I have a txt file (though I was planning to deploy it practically on vb files). It contains this: `Friend Const STR_NAME As String = "Test Name"`. Then I created a command.ps1 file in which I pasted your function and command but nothing prints out.

Comment: @kmrydlx You do need to output `$var` or just remove it at the bottom where it says `$var = ...`